# Generic map not compiling with nested structure

Tags: java, generics

I want to implement a map wrapper that use genericity to enforce a type relation between the key and the value.
The following code does not compile :

```
Map<Class<? extends Serializable>, List<List<? extends Serializable>>> collection = new HashMap();

private <T extends Serializable> void add(Class<T> type, List<List<T>> item) {
    collection.put(type, item);
}
```

whereas this compile :

```
Map<Class<? extends Serializable>, List<? extends Serializable>> collection = new HashMap();

private <T extends Serializable> void add(Class<T> type, List<T> item) {
    collection.put(type, item);
}
```

why is there a difference between a 2nd and a 3rd level generic type ?

Comment: There are several other questions that are also essentially the same -- the proposed dupe is the one among those I found whose answers I think are the best.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are *invariant*, the second type parameter of your map is `List<List<? extends Serializable>>`, that means that the second argument of `put` must match this *exactly*.

i.e. You can only add a `List` to the map if it has the exact parameter `List<? extends Serializable>`, and `T` is not *exactly* `? extends Serializable`.

You can fix this by having another `? extends` in your map and method declaration:

```
Map<Class<? extends Serializable>, List<? extends List<? extends Serializable>>> collection = new HashMap<>();

private <T extends Serializable> void add(Class<T> type, List<? extends List<T>> item) {
    collection.put(type, item);
}
```